# Sort list of citations by the year at the end of the key

Tags: sort

I've got some text like:

```
...many papers due to their interpretability and relatively low cost
\footnote{\citealt{
    alviPakistanSignLanguage2007,
    atzoriNinaproDatabaseResource2015,
    baudelCharadeRemoteControl1993,
    feinerVisualizingDimensionalVirtual1990,
    felsBuildingAdaptiveInterfaces1990,
    felsGloveTalkIIaNeuralnetworkInterface1998,
    frankhofmannSensorGloveAnthropomorphicRobot1995,
    heumerGraspRecognitionUncalibrated2007,
    immersioncorporationCyberGlove2001,
    kadousGRASPRecognitionAustralian1995,
    kesslerEvaluationCyberGloveWholehand1995,
    laviolaSurveyHandPosture1999,
    leeDeepLearningBased2020,
    leeSmartWearableHand2018,
    liangSignLanguageRecognition1996,
    mardiyantoDevelopmentHandGesture2017,
    murakamiGestureRecognitionUsing1991,
    rung-hueiliangRealtimeContinuousGesture1998,
    takahashiHandGestureCoding1991,
    wenMachineLearningGlove2020,
    wiseEvaluationFiberOptic1990,
    yuanHandGestureRecognition2020
}}.

Accelerometers measure linear acceleration in up to three axes. Inertial...
```

And I'd like to sort all those citations by their year in increasing order. I don't want to change the citation keys to start with the year. Is there some clever way to sort them in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ignore anything that's not a number

You can use `:sort n` that will ignore anything until the first (decimal) number as described in `:help sort`:

```
vi{
:'<,'>sort n
```

I noticed this will even sort the citations belonging to the same year alphabetically so this is clearly the best solution.

It was found by [beyarkay](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/43462/beyarkay) and posted as a comment. I include it in my answer for completeness.

#### Ignore by pattern

It's also possible to give `:sort` a pattern to be ignored.

To ignore letters and the hyphen, you could do something like my original answer below:

```
:'<,'>sort /[a-zA-Z-]\+/
```

or the much more elegant pattern proposed by [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble):

```
:'<,'>sort /\D\+/
```

#### Finishing touches

No matter which approach you use, you may end up with a result somewhat like below. As `:sort` orders *lines*, the line not terminated by a comma may end up in the middle of the list. I'd just manually double-check and fix it.

```tex
...many papers due to their interpretability and relatively low cost
\footnote{\citealt{
    feinerVisualizingDimensionalVirtual1990,
    felsBuildingAdaptiveInterfaces1990,
    wiseEvaluationFiberOptic1990,
    takahashiHandGestureCoding1991,
    murakamiGestureRecognitionUsing1991,
    baudelCharadeRemoteControl1993,
    kadousGRASPRecognitionAustralian1995,
    kesslerEvaluationCyberGloveWholehand1995,
    frankhofmannSensorGloveAnthropomorphicRobot1995,
    liangSignLanguageRecognition1996,
    felsGloveTalkIIaNeuralnetworkInterface1998,
    rung-hueiliangRealtimeContinuousGesture1998,
    laviolaSurveyHandPosture1999,
    immersioncorporationCyberGlove2001,
    heumerGraspRecognitionUncalibrated2007,
    alviPakistanSignLanguage2007,
    atzoriNinaproDatabaseResource2015,
    mardiyantoDevelopmentHandGesture2017,
    leeSmartWearableHand2018,
    yuanHandGestureRecognition2020      % <--- add a comma
    leeDeepLearningBased2020,
    wenMachineLearningGlove2020,        % <--- remove a comma
}}.

Accelerometers measure linear acceleration in up to three axes. Inertial...
```

Comment: :D this is exactly what I was hoping for, thanks so much! You can see my horribly inelegant attempt, I'm really glad I decided to ask (and learn something new) instead of sticking with what I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Glad I could help. BTW, I learned something new as well.

Comment: Looking through `:h :sort`, it seems like Bram gave us something even better: `:sort n` will ignore everything before the first number (which is exactly what we want). There's also options for floats, hexadecimals, octals, etc

Comment: Oops, I must have skipped that :) Feel free to post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Since there’s no hyphens, I’d write `/\a\+/` (or `\D` to ignore all non-digits)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes, there's one: "rung-hueiliang..." and I tripped on it on my first attempt. I'm guilty of not having spent any effort optimizing my regex, though. Your `/\D\+/` works great. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found an answer, but I'd be grateful to anybody with better vim-foo if they can find something better

After the section in `{}` is selected:

```
'<,'>s/\(.\+\(\d\d\d\d\)\)/\2\1/|'<,'>sort|'<,'>norm 4x
```

To explain:

- `'<,'>s/\(.\+\(\d\d\d\d\)\)/\2\1/` copy the year and paste it to the front
- `'<,'>sort` sort the citations
- `'<,'>norm 4x` delete the leading 4 digits which are the year.

It could be simplified a bit but it works.