# Vim mapping to make function parameters become multi-line?

Tags: key-bindings, regular-expression, functions

I'm looking for a minimal way to convert code that looks like this:

```py
my_function(param1, param2=value2, param4=a_function_call())
```

into something like:

```py
my_function(
    param1,
    param2=value2,
    param4=a_function_call(),
)
```

I'm sure there's a plugin that could work, but that seems pretty overkill for what can probably just be done with a function and a mapping, or possibly even just a clever regex. Also this often comes up in situations where I don't have a LSP/linter/formatter set up (like typing markdown snippets or in languages I don't use very often) so "just use formatting tool X" doesn't really cover the situations I care about. What if I've got some LaTeX citations in a similar format `\cite{key1, key2, key3}` and I want to get each key on a newline? I'd like something that doesn't care about the underlying language.

Some details:

- Trailing whitespace should be removed,
- Trailing commas should be added,
- The solution should also work for function definitions:

```
def my_function(param1, param2=value2, param3=value3):
```

should become:

```
def my_function(
    param1,
    param2=value2,
    param3=value3,
):
```

- Indentation should be consistent regardless of the starting indentation:

```
    my_function(param1, param2=value2, param4=a_function_call())
```

should become:

```
    my_function(
        param1,
        param2=value2,
        param4=a_function_call(),
    )
```

---

Edit: To clarify a comment, I'm not interested in a solution that works for language X or language Y. I want something that solves the generic formatting problem of converting a list of elements all on one line (separated by a delimiter and surrounded by some sort of brackets) and converts it into a list of elements where each element is on a different line. This happens most frequently in code, but also  in LaTeX, markdown, little bash scripts, etc, so I'm not interested in something that only works in one particular language.

Comment: That last trailing comma kills me :( How can this be valid then? In general I would just use something like this: `:s/, /,\r\t/g |:s/)/\r&/` and fix the remaining stuff manually, as this may not be hundert percent correct for all edge cases

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt
That regex ticks a lot of boxes, but (as you said) it'll only do one level of indentation even if two levels are required.  Generally I find "the remaining stuff" to take up a lot of time when doing it manually so I'd like a key mapping that "just works".

Comment: @romainl I've been largely just doing `:s/, /,\r/g` and then cleaning things up manually, but it's a big pain and feels very repetitive, exactly the sort of thing that vim probably can do for me if I knew how (hence asking for help here)

Comment: What did you try *to solve your problem*?

Comment: Could you tell us which language are you using?

Comment: Sorry @romainl I don't think I'm understanding you, here's what I think is the answer to your question but please clarify if I was wrong. I am hoping someone here who knows more about vim than I do can point to a clever way of solving my problem (kinda like what happened here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/43531/43462). The only solutions I can think of is to use a substitution (although I can't get this to fully work) or to record a macro (this has been pretty fragile and breaks often though). But I'm hoping there's someone smarter than myself who knows something that I don't.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I'll make an edit to clarify this, but I'm not interested in a solution that works for one particular language. I want to solve the problem of converting a list of items from being all on one line to being formatted with one item per line. This most often occurs with code, but also comes up with LaTeX, markdown, lists, etc.

Comment: @beyarkay in the question you link to, you found the best solution *yourself*. You should be able to do so again.

Comment: @Friedrich I appreciate the confidence (truly) but my first attempt was pretty shoddy in that linked question, and the best solution was only found after a commenter proposed their best solution. If there's a small chance someone could have a significantly better solution, I like to ask the question (since the expected value is positive)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `it takes a lot of time`. Visually selecting the lines and pushing `>` is too much time? You can easily repeat it using `.`. That should be done in a matter of seconds to fix.

Answer (score 1):

A first start might be using tpope’s surround plugin to do `cS((` to make the parens multi-line. Then you could attempt one of the substitutions like `:substitute/, /,\r/g` and clean up. But this last will fall apart as soon as one argument contains commas (say, `f(g(a, b), c)`).

Answer (score 1):

You could be interested to the following: [vim-argwrap](https://github.com/FooSoft/vim-argwrap/) plugin.

It provides an `:ArgWrap` command that seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to install a plugin, you could try Andrew Radev's [splitjoin](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim).

It works with a wide range of languages, and you can configure new ones if necessary. By default it uses `gS` to split a single line into multiple ones, or `gJ` to go back again, but this too is configurable.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this without a plugin, the following pure Vim solution relying on `:substitute` and `=` could be used. It's hard to provide a "works for all languages" solution as syntax differs between languages and there will also be the occasional edge case that breaks it.

Having said all that, here's:

```
:s/(\zs.*\ze)/\r&\r/|-1s/,\s*/,\r/g|normal j=g'.
```

The first `:substitute` command will put everything between the outer parenthesis on a line of its own. Due to the greediness of `*` it will also match inner parentheses.

The cursor will now be on the line with the closing parenthesis and we want to modify the line above, that's why we give a range of -1 to the second `:substitute`. It replaces each comma (optionally followed by whitespace) with a comma followed by a newline.

In a final step, go down one line to the closing parenthesis and use `=g'.` to filter all the lines up to the last change through `=`. This will indent the arguments, assuming it's setup correctly for the current `filetype`.